# How to include multiple files in ditto source

Tags: bash, macos, ditto

This seems like the kind of question that could be found in the man for ditto, but I've read that and googled this question with no answer.

I simply want to archive a few files using ditto, like this:

```
ditto -ckv file1 file2 file3 newfile.zip
```

It seems that ditto allows for multiple source files. But I get an error.

Does anyone if there's a way to make this work or can you confirm that ditto won't allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can do that with built-in `zip` command:

```
zip archive.zip file1 file2 file3
```

or, more simply:

```
zip archive.zip file[123]
```

**Original Answer**

You can do that with `7zip`.

---

Here I write (add) 3 files to an archive:

```
7z a archive.zip file1 file2 file3
```

---

Now, I check what's in it:

```
7z l archive.zip 

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs x64)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 2827 bytes (3 KiB)

Listing archive: archive.zip

--
Path = archive.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 2827

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2017-06-19 21:48:35 .....         1684          811  file1
2017-06-19 21:48:39 .....         1690          813  file2
2017-06-19 21:48:41 .....         1696          815  file3
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2017-06-19 21:48:41               5070         2439  3 files
```

---

I could equally check the contents with `unzip`:

```
unzip -l archive.zip 

Archive:  archive.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
     1684  06-19-2017 21:48   file1
     1690  06-19-2017 21:48   file2
     1696  06-19-2017 21:48   file3
---------                     -------
     5070                     3 files
```

---

I installed `7zip` with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install p7zip
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply!  I assume it can't be done with ditto, but given that zip is just another built-in command, I can use it instead.

Comment: `zip` can corrupt the contents of a signed app bundle, "destroying the UTF8 encoding." See [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/116831).

Answer (score 0):

The manual suggest that only one source file system object can create an archive.

```
ditto -c [-z | -j | -k] [-v] [-V] [-X] [<options>] src dst_archive
```

To copy multiple files, you could copy files or hard link files to a directory then zip the directory with ditto.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it can't be done with ditto. I'm using a bash script to work with existing folder structures, so moving the files around wouldn't work for this particular situation.